# How can I rewrite my code to make it simpler?

Tags: programming, code-review

Two months ago,I written a function `IRobot` to caculate the $I_{xx},I_{yy},I_{zz}$ and  $I_{xy},I_{xz},I_{yz}$,shown as below:

```
  IRobot[IStyle_String, ρ_, VaribleRange_List] := Module[
   {IRobotResult},
    IRobotResult =
    Which[
        IStyle == "xx", Integrate[ρ (y^2 + z^2),
          {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]}, 
          {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]},
          {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}],
        IStyle == "yy", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + z^2),
          {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]}, 
          {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]}, 
          {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}],
        IStyle == "zz", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + y^2),
          {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]},
          {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]},
          {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}],
        IStyle == "xy", Integrate[ρ x y,
           {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]},
           {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]}, 
           {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}],
        IStyle == "xz", Integrate[ρ x z,
           {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]}, 
           {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]},
           {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}],
       IStyle == "yz", Integrate[ρ y z,
           {z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]}, 
           {y,VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]},
           {x,VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}]
    ]
  ]
```

And I can use it correctly.

```
 IRobot["xx", ρ, {{-h1, 0}, {-r1, r1}, {-L1 - Sqrt[r1^2 - y^2], Sqrt[r1^2 - y^2]}}]
 (*===>*)
 1/12 h1 r1 (4 h1^2 (2 L1 + \[Pi] r1) + r1^2 (8 L1 + 3 \[Pi] r1)) ρ
```

However,I would like to simplify my code by `Similarity`,my trail as below:

```
 Flatten /@Thread@List[{z, y, x},
   Apply[Part[VaribleRange, ##] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}]]
(*==>*)
 {{z, VaribleRange[[1, 1]], VaribleRange[[1, 2]]},
  {y, VaribleRange[[2, 1]], VaribleRange[[2, 2]]},
  {x, VaribleRange[[3, 1]], VaribleRange[[3, 2]]}}
```

### Trial 1

```
IRobot[IStyle_String, ρ_, VaribleRange_List] := Module[
   {IRobotResult,intlist},
   intlist=
    Flatten /@Thread@List[{z, y, x},
   Apply[Part[VaribleRange, ##] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}]];
    IRobotResult =
    Which[
        IStyle == "xx", Integrate[ρ (y^2 + z^2),intlist],
        IStyle == "yy", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + z^2),intlist],
        IStyle == "zz", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + y^2),intlist],
        IStyle == "xy", Integrate[ρ x y,intlist],
        IStyle == "xz", Integrate[ρ x z,intlist],
        IStyle == "yz", Integrate[ρ y z,intlist]
    ]
  ]
```

Unfortunately,it failed.

### Trail2

```
 IRobot[IStyle_String, ρ_, VaribleRange_List] := Module[
   {IRobotResult,intlist},
   intlist[z_,y_,x_,range_]:=
    Flatten /@Thread@List[{z, y, x},
   Apply[Part[range, ##] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}]];
    IRobotResult =
    Which[
        IStyle == "xx", Integrate[ρ (y^2 + z^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "yy", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + z^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "zz", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + y^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "xy", Integrate[ρ x y,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "xz", Integrate[ρ x z,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "yz", Integrate[ρ y z,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]]
    ]
  ]
```

Also it ends in failure!

### Or

I want to by

```
 Which@@(
 Flatten@{IStyle == #1, Integrate[ρ #2, intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]]} & @@@
 {{"xx", (y^2 + z^2)}, {"yy", (x^2 + z^2)}, {"zz", (x^2 + y^2)},
  {"xy", x y}, {"xz", x z}, {"yz", y z}})
  (*==>*)
```

[image]

to achieve

```
  Which[
        IStyle == "xx", Integrate[ρ (y^2 + z^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "yy", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + z^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "zz", Integrate[ρ (x^2 + y^2),intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "xy", Integrate[ρ x y,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "xz", Integrate[ρ x z,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]],
        IStyle == "yz", Integrate[ρ y z,intlist[z,y,x,VaribleRange]]
    ]
```

**So my question is why and how to revise it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proposal

I recommend something like this:

```
IRobot2[IStyle_String, ρ_, VaribleRange_List] :=
  Block[{x, y, z},
    With[{expr = 
     Switch[IStyle,
       "xx", (y^2 + z^2),
       "yy", (x^2 + z^2), 
       "zz", (x^2 + y^2),
       "xy", x y,
       "xz", x z,
       "yz", y z
     ]},
     Integrate[ρ expr, ##] & @@ Join[{{z}, {y}, {x}}, VaribleRange, 2]
    ]
  ]
```

The [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html) is there to localize `x`, `y`, `z` to prevent these Symbols from incorrectly evaluating while they are manipulated, before passing them to `Integrate` using [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).

---

### Code review

I first posted my recommendation above because it is faster for me to do so than to analyze and debug your attempts that did not work but as requested I will do the latter now.

The **Trial 1** code throws this error when used:

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {{z,-h1,0},{y,-r1,r1},{x,-L1-Sqrt[r1^2-Power[<<2>>]],Sqrt[r1^2-y^2]}}. >>

That should draw your attention to that part of the code, meaning `intlist` and how it is used in `Integrate`.  The problem arises because `intlist` is (indeed) a list, whereas the parameters of `Integrate` need to be a *sequence*, i.e. `1, 2, 3` rather than `{1, 2, 3}`.  In my own code above I used [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) for this because it is more universal and I could not remember off-hand the way in which `Integrate` evaluated its arguments.  However your **Trial 1** code can be corrected by wrapping the existing right-hand-side definition of `intlist` in `Sequence @@ ( . . . )`, or a bit more concisely:

```
intlist = Sequence @@ (
  Flatten /@ Thread@{ {z, y, x}, Array[VaribleRange[[##]] &, {3, 2}] }
 )
```

I stated that using `SlotSequence` is more robust.  Here is an example where it is needed:

```
iterSeq = Sequence[{x, 5}, {i, x}];
Table[x + i^2, iterSeq]              (*failure*)

iterList = {{x, 5}, {i, x}} ;
Table[x + i^2, ##] & @@ iterList     (*success*)
```

(`Attributes[Table]` includes `HoldAll` and `iterSeq` is not evaluated.)

**Trial 2** can be corrected in the same manner.

The second attempt at **Trial 2** was clever but you didn't quite get it right.  [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Which.html) needs input in the form of:

```
Which[
  test1, value1,
  test2, value2,
  . . .
]
```

While your code results in:

```
Which[
  {test1, value1},
  {test2, value2},
  . . .
]
```

Also you are not doing anything to [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) the "value" expressions, therefore `Integrate` will evaluate prematurely.

To correct these problems we need to `Flatten` the entire expression, not the sub-lists, and we need to add expression holding:

```
Which @@ Flatten[
 {IStyle == #1, Unevaluated @ Integrate[ρ #2, intlist[z, y, x, VaribleRange]]} & @@@
   {{"xx", (y^2 + z^2)},
    {"yy", (x^2 + z^2)},
    {"zz", (x^2 + y^2)},
    {"xy", x y},
    {"xz", x z},
    {"yz", y z}}
]
```

`Unevaluated` should suffice here (I did not actually test this section of code) but if not you could use `Hold` in its place, then add a [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReleaseHold.html) outside of `Which`.

Comment: ♦,+1,Perfect!This solution make the function `IRobot` become more refine and elegant.By the way,I would like to why my trail cannot work normally or can you give me `some suggestion` about `writing program`.Thanks sincerely!

Comment: @tangshutao Comment again on this answer some time tomorrow to remind me, and I'll try to explain where your attempt went wrong.  I need to sleep now.

Comment: ♦,Ok,thanks ror your warm help.May you have a good dream!

Comment: @tangshutao Update complete.

Comment: ♦.Wow,Thanks very much.From your reputation rank,I know you are a Mathematica expert!!

Comment: ♦,I test the code of `trial2` according your method.It failed owing to `intlist[z, y, x, VaribleRange]`,so I try to:`IRobot[IStyle_String, ρ_, VaribleRange_List] :=   Module[{IRobotResult, intlist, z, y, x},    intlist =     Sequence @@ (Flatten /@        Thread@{{z, y, x}, Array[VaribleRange[[##]] &, {3,2}]});   IRobotResult =    Which @@      Flatten[{IStyle == #1,          Integrate[ρ #2, intlist]} & @@@                {{"xx", (y^2 + z^2)}, {"yy", (x^2 + z^2)}, {"zz", (x^2 + y^2)}, {"xy", x y}, {"xz", x z}, {"yz",y z}}]]`.It give the `wrong` result `without any warning`.

Comment: @tangshutao Sorry for any bad information I may have given.  I'm pretty tired right now, but if I have time and interest later I'll try to correct the mistake.  Just to be sure, the `IRobot2` code at the top of the answer *is* working, correct?

Comment: ♦,The function `IRobot2` that you give is correct.The problem is your correction of my `original function`.and the first correction right ,while the second correction cannot work normally.